# Read a file as byte array using C++?

Tags: c++

I want to read my .exe file as byte so can i edit its bytes later, i tried to write a code but it gives me this error :

> error: invalid conversion from 'LPVOID {aka void*}' to 'LPBYTE {aka
> unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]|

this is my code:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("0x2.exe", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        // get file size
        DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);

        // decrypt and obtain decrypted bytes
        LPVOID lpFileBytes = Crypt(hFile, dwFileSize);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        //free(lpFileBytes);

         //execute file
         //

    LPBYTE lpBuffer = lpFileBytes ;
```

i crypt the file 0x2.exe, and i decrypt it by this line :

```
LPVOID lpFileBytes = Crypt(hFile, dwFileSize);
```

now i issume i have the orignal bytes in **lpFileBytes** , so when i do this :

```
LPBYTE lpBuffer = lpFileBytes
```

it gives me that error .

Comment: And why are you instead not using specialised applications for that purpose? You know there are special apps to do that, don't you? An example would be Ollydebugger

Comment: You can't convert from `void*` to another pointer type without a cast in c++

Comment: @d4rk4ng31, i need to open it using c++

Comment: @AlanBirtles, what should i do ?

Comment: @Test221 If you use a cast it will compile `LPBYTE lpBuffer = static_cast<LPBYTE>(lpFileBytes);` whether that's the right thing to do however is a different question. There are a few things in what you're saying that ring alarm bells for me.

Comment: I would use `reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>` from your LPVOID pointer.